# Can I find all X0-1 pieces without having the required level?

Tags: fallout-4

For example, the helmet you can steal from the Prydrwen.  I'm curious if you can find all pieces of the X0-1.

Comment: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/X-01_power_armor already answers the question, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

No, all power armor spawns are based on level, except for the BoS and Atom Cats. However, they have T-60, not X-01.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to 35 Court and can find a full set there through 35 Court is unmarked you can find it west of the customs house

Comment: Yeah, but it is still dependent on level. At lower levels you might not get X-01 armor, but the lower variants. Above level 28 is when X-01 spawns.